# Trying to Integrate Extent reports with Selenium WebDriver Event Listener

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, extentreports, selenium-extent-report, webdrivereventlistener

I am trying to integrate the Extent Reports with Selenium WebDriver Event listeners so that after every action (like navigateTo, clickon, elementChangeValue, etc) the logs get added to the extent report for every action and exceptions. Any thoughts on how can I achieve this since I think I cant pass the EventTest object as a parameter in extended/implemented WebDriverEventListener's methods.

Comment: Store the EventTest in a ThreadLocal variable. Access it anywhere in the same thread. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html

Comment: @Grasshopper - Thanks for your suggestion. It will be great help if you can add some example. I am not exactly following how can I use ThreadLocal here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is possible but you can create you own methods for navigateTo, clickon, elementChangeValue, etc and add the actions like steps in the extent report.

For example:

```
public void navigateTo(String url) throws Exception {
    driver.get(url);
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.className("some_element_in_page"));
        TestListener.getExtentTest().log(Status.INFO, "Login successful");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        TestListener.getExtentTest().log(Status.FAIL, "Login failed");
    }
}
```

[Here](https://www.swtestacademy.com/extentreports-testng/) is a tutorial that might help you.